# How to get <table> <th> and <tr> to be draggable in a responsive way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <table
      class="table table-hover w-100 custom-table table-responsive align-middle"
    >
      <thead>
        <draggable v-model="tableHeaders" :options="{ handle: '.handle' }">
          <th
            class="handle"
            style="text-align: center"
            v-for="header in tableHeaders"
            :key="header"
          >
            {{ header }}
          </th>
        </draggable>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <draggable
          v-model="tableData"
          :options="{
            handle: '.handle',
            ghostClass: 'ghost-class',
            chosenClass: 'chosen-class',
          }"
        >
          <tr v-for="item in tableData" :key="item.id" class="handle">
            <td v-for="header in tableHeaders" style="text-align: center">
              {{ item[header.toLowerCase()] }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </draggable>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableHeaders: [
        "Names",
        "Language",
        "Country",
        "Game",
        "Bought",
        "Balance",
        "Rating",
        "Winnings",
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec",
      ],
      tableData: [
        {
          id: 1,
          names: "Alice Anderson",
          language: "English",
          country: "USA",
          game: "Chess",
          bought: "true",
          balance: "5000",
          rating: "1",
          winnings: "1000",
          jan: "65243",
          feb: "64235",
          mar: "60845",
          apr: "61245",
          may: "63542",
          jun: "66452",
          jul: "60124",
          aug: "58142",
          sep: "60312",
          oct: "59842",
          nov: "60125",
          dec: "61520",
        },
...


<style>
th:hover,
td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ghost-class {
  position: fixed !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.chosen-class {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.custom-table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.custom-table td,
.custom-table th {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100vw;
}
.custom-table th {
  color: #6a6c8f;
}
.custom-table .handle {
  cursor: move;
}

.custom-table .handle:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover {
  background-color: #323346;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover td,
.custom-table .handle:hover th {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover .chosen-class,
.custom-table .handle:hover .ghost-class {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover .chosen-class {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover .ghost-class {
  cursor: move;
}
</style>
```

Ive only included one piece of data for reference, but lets say under "Country" it might say "USA" but it wont appear like theyre in the same cell - USA will be however many pixels to the left of country, so everything is draggable right now but the data doesnt stay uniform and i need it to stay in uniform cells.

I tried using classes like this, messing with margin: 0 auto, justify content, align items... etc to no avail.

```
.th-class,
.td-class {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

here is my current project and how its messing up the styling/responsiveness, notice how the columns don't stay uniform

[image]

and here is an example of how i want it to be

https://www.ag-grid.com/example/